# Multiple Credit Cards that are Shared

Tags: yodlee

I'm having a data issue I'm not sure how to handle.

Scenario: A company has a shared credit card. Which means, it is **one** account, but two people have access to the account, each person with his own credit card with his name on it. Let's call these people Charles and David, and assume they have a Chase account.

When I add this Chase login to Yodlee, it pulls the account THREE times, as:

- "Chase - Credit Card - CREDIT CARD"
- "Chase - Credit Card - DAVID"
- "Chase - Credit Card - CHARLES"

It does this even though they are the same account. (I guess when you login to Chase it shows up multiple times).

All three are coming in with different ID numbers. So there is no way for me to know they are all the same account. My code thinks they are three different accounts, because they have different names and ID numbers.

As a result the account gets stored in my app three times, and the transactions three times.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I didn't find the two proposed solutions useful. Because we cannot rely on a user to find the right bank (suggestion 1) and we also cannot rely on the user to click Deactivate on the duplicate card accounts (suggestion 2). I did find that the main card has an acctType of credits and the other duplicates have an acctType of unknown, so for now I'm just skipping any acctType unknown accounts. I don't know if this will help for all banks though. I really think Yodlee should fix this internally by detecting duplicate cards and flagging them.

Comment: But thanks for you help. I really appreciate that you monitor and respond to Yodlee questions here. Thank you!

Comment: I would raise this internally and will ask our engineering team to do brainstorm about it. Keeping asking these questions and we would love to brainstorm and provide you solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. First thing is to look for a particular site i.e., if Yodlee supports the Business Card site for that particular institution or not. As sometimes some of these Bank websites have a different login URL which can be either accessed by a different credentials or might be by the same and that will show you only 1 actual credit card account instead of 3.
2. In case the Business site is either not available or not supported by Yodlee(though you can request Yodlee to support the site and it could be prioritized based on the business use case), else you could call [deactivateItemAccount](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/deactivateItemAccount) API. This will deactivate a particular itemAccount and you can call this for those duplicate accounts.